# Event for multiple div's with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT: I needed to use a class, thanks for pointing that one out to me

I have the following div's:

```
<div class="section-link" id="section-tooltip" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="right">
    <div class="section-features" style="display: none;">
    Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-link" id="section-tooltip" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="right">
    <div class="section-features" style="display: none;">
    Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-link" id="section-tooltip" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="right">
    <div class="section-features" style="display: none;">
    Content
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see they are all using the same id, I am trying to make a popover in bootstrap with the following JQuery however it is only doing it for one div and I am trying to have it do it for them all without having to set individual id's.

```
$('#section-tooltip').each(function(){
        $(this).popover({
    trigger: "hover",
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $(this).children('div:first').html();
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: the id must be unique http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: Why do you want non-unique id's? That kinda goes against the definition of an ID

Comment: You need to use a class!

Comment: Use `$('.section-link')` as your selector since they already all have the same class. And you don't need to use `.each()` - just call `.popover()` on that selector

Comment: Aha let me try the class, and I need to use non unique id's because of my content management system

Comment: Ooh that's a bit dirty

Comment: Awesome this has done the job :)

Comment: have you read the documentation of id attribute in html ?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the ID to a class, then modify your code:

```
<div class="section-link section-tooltip" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="right">
    <div class="section-features" style="display: none;">
    Content
    </div>
</div>

$('.section-tooltip').each(function(){
    $(this).popover({
        trigger: "hover",
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
            return $(this).children('div:first').html();
        }
    });
});
```

This is assuming that you have other elements using the same class (`.section-link`) to which you **do not** wish this behaviour to apply. Otherwise just use that class instead.

Comment: (just saying) the `.each()` is unnecessary

Comment: I haven't modified the code, just substituted the id for a class by way of example

Comment: Of course, that's why I said "just saying". Sometimes though, it's nice to suggest/improve code. Again, just saying

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.section-link').each(function(){
        $(this).popover({
    trigger: "hover",
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $(this).children('div:first').html();
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FROM: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

> Definition and Usage The id attribute specifies a unique id for an
>   HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).
>
> The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet,
>   and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with
>   the specific id.